# cant break blocks in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My daughter has just bought minecraft and is playing in creative mode, cheats are off, we have tried /gamemode 1, also /gamemode c and other suggestions. We have created a new world and still cant break blocks. Pressing and holding down the left click on mouse does not get any response on screen - the hand does not even attempt to break anything grass, wood, stone - nothng happens. We can fly so def in creative mode. Please help as she is getting really upset that she has spent £17 and can not get it to work. She plays on the iPad with no problem but wanted the extra options you get on the PC. Thanks

Comment: The `/gamemode` commands don't work with cheats off, FYI, but since she can fly around the game mode isn't the problem. In the menu, under Controls, what does it say for Button 1? Does it say "Attack", or something else?

Comment: @MBraedley Can't be, since this question's details show that it's not a game mode problem, which is what that one is about. We don't have any other "definitely in Creative mode but can't break blocks" questions already.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You'll notice that the linked question was updated 5 hours ago to be a little more broad.  We also had a discussion on [the Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/breaking-minecraft-blocks) about this.

Comment: @MBraedley Ah, I see that now, ok. (As an adherent of the Dr Strangedupe doctrine I can't agree that it's an exact dupe, but I realise it's a minority opinion here.)

Comment: I think you're trying to break blocks in creative with a sword. You can't. Use something else like your hand.